# preg_replace doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have problem with preg_replace, I need it to replace `<td class="td_supltrid_3" width="11%"><p>  4A8</p>` with only 4A8. When I use this pattern:

```
'/\<td class\=\"td_supltrid_3\" width\=\"11%\"\>\<p\>  ...\<\/p\>/'
```

it doesn't find it. However, when I use preg_match, it finds searched expression without problem. Can you tell me there is the problem? Whole code:

```
preg_replace('/\<td class\=\"td_supltrid_3\" width\=\"11%\"\>\<p\>  (...)\<\/p\>/', '$1', $str)
```

Comment: You need to STOP using regexes on html. This would've been FAR easier using DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `(...)` to `(.*?)`, which will grab everything up to the trailing `</p>`

```
<?php echo preg_replace('/<td class\=\"td_supltrid_3\" width\=\"11%\"><p>(.*?)<\/p>/', '$1', '<td class="td_supltrid_3" width="11%"><p> 4A8</p>'); ?>
```

Comment: And when I need there to be exactly 3 chars?

Comment: Do you want it to only match if there are 3 characters?  `preg_match('/\<td class\=\"td_supltrid_3\" width\=\"11%\"\>\<p\>([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\<\/p\>/', '<td class="td_supltrid_3" width="11%"><p>4SA</p>', $matches);` $matches[1] will have the match iff the contents of the p tag are 3 characters